# Trying to create a batch file to select a file to open

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file that searches for a specific series of files by name and create a list to choose which file to run/open. My problem is I do not know how to set each result to a variable.

The code below is what I have currently:

```
@echo off
::The code below requests for the user to enter part of the file name
::that he/she is interested in opening. This either provides a file name
::or provides a list of similar file names. I would like to take the list
::and create a numbered list from the user can select by entering the 
::associated number.
echo Please enter part of the file name that you would like to search for.
set INPUT=%input%
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
dir Template_VBAForm*%INPUT%*.xlsm /b /s

pause
```

Comment: It would at least help were you to `Rem`ark your script so that we know what each line of code is intended to do. At the moment your code asks for a `Y` or `N` as input which means `%resp%` would do a recursive `Dir` looking for a file named either `Template_VBAForm*Y*.xlsm` or `Template_VBAForm*N*.xlsm`. Lines `2` & `3` effectively do nothing, is that the intention?

Comment: @Compo please see my edited code. I incidentally entered test code.

Comment: You are effectively saying, this is some code which doesn't do what I want it to do and I have shown no attempt to change that! I would suggest you use a `for` loop to run `dir` both saving the resultant file names as variables and outputting them as a sequentially numbered list prepended accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example to perhaps get you started.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "INPUT=Please enter your part file name search term: "
Set "resp=Where/R .\ "Template_VBAForm*%INPUT%*.xlsm""
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('%resp%') Do (Set/A "i+=1"
    Call Set "[%%i%%]=%%A")
Set [||GoTo EndIt
Set/P "INPUT=Please enter an item number: "
If Defined [%INPUT%] Call Echo %%[%INPUT%]%%
:EndIt
Pause
```